# how --py-files works internally in pyspark

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

I am new to pySpark. I have used --py-files like below in spark-submit command to copy all files to worker nodes.

```
spark-submit --master yarn-client  --driver-memory 4g --py-files /home/valli/pyFiles.zip /home/valli/main.py
```

In logs I observed that it is storing pyFiles.zip in .sparkStaging directory like below.

```
hdfs://cdhstltest/user/valli/.sparkStaging/application_1550968677175_9659/pyFiles.zip
```

When I copied above file into my specific local directory it is still showing like a zip file and unable to read files in it. But when I try to find out the current files directory it is showing with hdfs_directory/pyfiles.zip/module1.py and able to execute py file. As far as I know --py-files will copy all .py files in zip folder into worker nodes by automatically unzipping.

Can anyone please help me in understanding what is happening behind the screen ?

Thanks in advance.